# Как написать несколько вложенных циклов в одну строку Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список списков:

```
a = [[['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Как можно вот такую конструкцию прописать в одну строку:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] == 1:
            b.append(j[1])
```

Пробовал вот такое, что нибудь - ошибка:

```
b = [j[1] for j in [for i in a] if j[0] == 1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы с использованием i во всех ипостасях не перебарщиваете?

Comment: Главное подумайте надо ли писать строку сомнительной читаемости вместо легко читаемого цикла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во первых подозреваю, что `for i in i:` - это слишком круто для нашего простого сообщества :)

как вы думаете, что делает данная строчка?

а вообще можно сделать так:

вместо

```
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] == 1:
            b.append(j[1])
```

так:

```
b = [j[1] for i in a for j in i if j[0] == 1]
```

если я правильно с вашими `i` разобрался :)

Comment: Спасибо)) 'как вы думаете, что делает данная строчка?' - получается не то, что требовалось))

Comment: но еcли мой вариант с повторяющимися i сделать ступеньками как я привел в начале вопроса, то отрабатывает ведь правильно, почему одной строкой так?)

Comment: @ChikChirik потому что области видимости, как я думаю, внутри цикла именно локальная `i`, над циклом - другая `i`, но вообще НИКОГДА так не делайте - код должен быть понятным, красивым и работоспособным :) без потенциально уязвимых мест

Comment: Добавил в вопрос картинку, у меня во так почему-то, у вас сработало как нужно?

Comment: вот так попробуйте `b = [j[1] for i in a for j in i if j[0] == 1]`

Comment: да, так работает, спасибо